# Получение имени пользователя через VK API

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, никак не могу получить имя пользователя через vk_api

```
$pz = 'сайт.ру';
$url = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=******&client_secret=***&code=".$_GET['code']."&redirect_uri=".$pz;
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$decode=json_decode($file_contents);
```

так получаю access_token и ид пользователя потом:

```
$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?uid=".$decode->user_id."&fields=uid,first_name,last_name,nickname,screen_name,sex,bdate,city,country,timezone,photo,photo_medium&access_token=".$decode->access_token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$decode2 = json_decode($file_contents);
echo $decode2->uid;
```

Вот что получаю:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uid in /usr/home/lars/htdocs/cod.php on line 23

Хотя var_dump прекрасно всё показывает.

Comment: @keis, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: что показывает  `var_dump( $decode)` и `var_dump( $decode2)` ?

Comment: var_dump($decode):
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["access_token"]=> string(71) "13e0594314a6adcc14a6adccc31497e2df114a614a7a1ca440ed832d0335e472d396df8" ["expires_in"]=> int(0) ["user_id"]=> int(122090639) } 
var_dump($decode2):
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["response"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["uid"]=> int(122090639) ["first_name"]=> string(12) "Изнаур" ["last_name"]=> string(22) "Бексултанов" } } }
я просто убрал значения fields для примера-что бы меньше данных выводило

Comment: постарался через XML получить ответ всё то же самое var_dump всё прекрасно показывает а echo на этот раз даже ошибки не выдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыли "response":

```
echo $decode2->response[0]->uid;
```